# Запись несколько переменных в ByteArray

Tags: c#

записываю число в байтовый массив и далее массив отправляю в сокет клиенту.

```
uint a = 1;
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
handler.Send(b);
```

Но как записывать несколько переменных в массив байтов, например строку, uint, int и прочие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу ещё один способ:

```
uint a = 1;
int b = 2;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(a);
    writer.Write(b);

    var bytes = stream.ToArray();
    handler.Send(bytes);
}
```

У `BinaryWriter` метод `Write` имеет множество перегрузок.

PS: Читать из байтового массива можно по аналогии с помощью `BinaryReader`.

Comment: Спасибо, более удобный способ) А вы могли бы привести пример чтения, немного не понимаю.

Comment: Вот получение `bytes = new byte[1024];
                            bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);`, как получить uint из потока?

Comment: @Александр - а до этого вы как получали? И вообще, не спрашивайте в комментариях, задайте новый вопрос (создайте новую тему).

Answer (score 2):

```
uint a = 1;
byte[] a1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
double b = 1.234;
byte[] a2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);

byte[] arr = new byte[a1.Length + a2.Length];
Array.Copy(a1, 0, arr, 0, a1.Length);
Array.Copy(a2, 0, arr, a1.Length, a2.Length);

handler.Send(arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а может быть есть более короткий способ? Просто мне нужно вносить в массив большое количество значений и если пользоваться таким способом, то код будет слишком велик

Comment: @Александр Иметь массив значений и обрабатывать их в цикле.